# How do I make it so that the user can choose the gender of a person?

Tags: java, oop, enums, switch-statement, enter

Please tell me, I put a variable in the enum constructor that shows the gender of a person male and female. I want the user to choose what gender They will be. For Example, 1-Husband, 2-Wife. How do I do this?

````
        
 
        Gender gen =  Gender.MAN;
 
        Person person1 = new Person(gen);
        
        
        ArrayList <Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
        
        people.add(person1);
 
        
    }
}```

```  public class Person {
    private  Gender gen;
    
  
    public Person ( Gender gen){
    
        this.gen = gen;
      
      
  }```


``` public enum Gender {
    MAN("Man"),
    WOMAN("Woman");
    private String translation;
    
    Gender(String translation){
        this.translation = translation;
        
    }
    
    public String getGender(){
        return translation;
        
    }
    
    
} ```
````

Comment: The question - as is - is quite unclear. The presented code seems to work. Can you please [edit] your question and explain what it is you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Artemy, Is this what you mean?

```
public enum Gender {
    MAN("Man", "1", "M"),
    WOMAN("Woman", "2", "W");

    private List<String> translation;

    Gender(String... translation) {
        this.translation = Arrays.asList(translation);
    }

    public static Gender getGender(String value) {
        if (MAN.translation.contains(value)) {
            return MAN;
        } else if (WOMAN.translation.contains(value)) {
            return WOMAN;
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(value);
    }
}
```